# Is there a way in python to make a new list from 2 lists where the first list values are used to make up the lists of the new list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

For example if I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [2,3]
list2 = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

The new list should become

```
newlist = [[a,b], [c,d,e]]
```

So the values of the first list make up the amount of values inside the nested lists.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076154/how-to-divide-python-list-into-sublists-of-unequal-length)

Comment: Couldn't add an answer in time but you can use `itertools.islice`: `it = iter(list2); newlist = [list(islice(it, n)) for n in list1]`

Comment: Just posted an answer to the referenced/dup question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072159/225020

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

**Code:**

```
list1 = [2,3]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

rv = []
start = 0
for i in list1:
    rv.append(list2[start:start+i])
    start += i
```

**Output:**

```
>>> rv
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```